# where can happen merge conflicts in git between branches?

Tags: merge, branch

Hy,

1 .What are the most common scenarios where can happen merge conflicts in git between branches?

2 How to know when they are going to happen?

3. If I have a master branch and other evolution branch, if I have modified one file in the evolution branch and this file exists in master branch, when merging from evolution to master, how git determine merge conflicts or not between files in different branches? I mean, its easy for git to determine when there are conflicts when changes(from two different developers) point to the same file physically speaking but merge between branches we are talking about different files physically speaking, files in one branch and others in other branch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) When since you made your evolution branch you have edited the same line of code in both branches.

For example say you branch `evolution` from `master` and you have `main.py` and a week later you edit line 253. Two days after that someone edits line 253 in `main.py` on the `evolution` branch. Now when you try to merge `evolution` into `master` you'll get a merge conflict. The best way to prevent this is communication. Who is working on what, what you should change and what you shouldn't.

2) You never really know until they happen. You can do a "dry run" merge just to see if there are any conflicts using `git merge --no-commit --no-ff $BRANCH`. As I said above, the best way to avoid them is communication between individuals.

3) All files that you have tracked in `evolution` will be merged into `master`. Even if these files don't yet exist in `master`. If they have the same name but are completely different (and you've edited the file in master since you've branched) that's a merge conflict.

Comment: But its not needed to edit the same line to have a conflict in two branches, just editing the same file into differente branches and then trying to merge them, right?